# Can I use the same login for a video conversation and text conversation simultaneously?

Tags: java, android, webrtc, quickblox, quickblox-android

I have an android application based on the videochat-sample. I want to use a text chat to send information between the participants in the videochat. Can i simply use the same login?

Comment: Please, be more specific. What did you write so far? What login do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, sure, you need use same login for text-chat and vide-chat functionality